# It's is possible to use SOEM to communicate directly to a AC Servo Drive using ROS?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, servo, ethercat

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to develop a cartesian robot of 5 DOF without using a PLC. The AC servo drive that I have can communicate via CANopen or EtherCAT (and other protocols too). Choosing to use EtherCAT now I can, in the future, use CoE theorically. But, being a total beginner in ROS, I need to know if I am in the right way or using ROS with one of these protocols is impossible to archive sucess in this project?

Using a industrial PC with ubuntu 18.04 LTS and ROS Melodic.

ps.: sorry for my bad english.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316715/it%27s-is-possible-to-use-soem-to-communicate-directly-to-a-ac-servo-drive-using-ros?/) by [Hyperion](https://answers.ros.org/users/40208/hyperion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-02-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-26**:
It's not ethercat, but for canopen, you could look at [ros_canopen](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_canopen).

**Comment by [Hyperion](https://answers.ros.org/users/40208/hyperion/) on 2019-02-26**:
But checking the page of ROS-Industrial they say that SOEM is a open-source EtherCAT (https://github.com/mgruhler/soem). I'm wrong to believe it's possible to use EtherCAT to control servos with ROS?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-26**:
I don't believe I commented on the state of ethercat support. I just wanted to make you aware of the canopen support.

**Comment by [Hyperion](https://answers.ros.org/users/40208/hyperion/) on 2019-02-26**:
Thank you! But one more question: can you indicate a good (or complete) tutorial to do that with CANopen?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-26**:
No, I wouldn't know of any.

There are quite a few questions about `ros_canopen` on this site (ie: ROS Answers) though. Perhaps those can be of help.

Use Google to search for them (something like: `ros_canopen site:answers.ros.org`).

**Comment by [Hyperion](https://answers.ros.org/users/40208/hyperion/) on 2019-02-28**:
And if I choose to use Ethernet/IP, what you opinion about it? (Remember, I need to control servo drivers with a industrial PC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Hyperion sorry for the very late answer.

Yes, you are totally on the right track with this.
You can implement CoE using SOEM, e.g. There is a catkinized version of SOEM released into melodic, which should allow you to call `sudo apt install ros-melodic-soem`.

But I recommend to check out the [Usage section](https://github.com/mgruhler/soem#usage) of the ReadMe to make sure you don't run into include problems with the non-conform package layout the SOEM originally has...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hyperion](https://answers.ros.org/users/40208/hyperion/) on 2019-03-12**:
Thanks for the answer, I will try!!! But one more question: I found the ArmorBlock 1732 of Allen-Bradley that works as a sensor hub and operates over Ethernet/IP. You know anything about if is possible to connect the ROS directly with the device? I saw that Ethernet/IP package in ROS seems to be depreciated. You think is worth a try?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-03-12**:
sorry, can't help with that...

**Comment by [Hyperion](https://answers.ros.org/users/40208/hyperion/) on 2019-03-12**:
Don't worry, thanks for the help.